# ACPI PCC probe failed on Ubuntu installation from usb

Tags: boot, grub2, system-installation, acpi, usb-installation

I'm trying to install Ubuntu 15.04 on a HP Vivienne Tam netbook (throwing away Windows).
With Universal USB Installer I prepared the flash drive in order to proceed with the installation. 
When the computer starts, it shows me different options: try ubuntu, install Ubuntu etc.
Both with the install and try option, I get a gray screen with the `ACPI PCC probe failed` message, after that the screen become black.
I read that could be the nvidia drivers, but how can I manage the drivers if Ubuntu is not installed?

Comment: this might cause by ACPI incompatibility. Try to boot with `acpi=off` during the installation.  Refer to this : [BootOptions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootOptions). Let me know if its working so I can write this as an answer.

Comment: I tried but when the "installation screen" shows I cannot use F1-F6, they simply "refresh" the installation screen. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: try `ctrl + alt + 6` for `F6`.

Comment: I get [this screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97087/IMG_0780.JPG)
Neither the F6 nor the `ctrl+alt+6` work. :(

Comment: you need to go to `advanced options`

Comment: @AizuddinZali I tried it, but the advanced options are empty, there is only the `back` choice :/

Comment: Ok, I found the advanced menu in the `Help` section. Now I get [this screen](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/97087/IMG_0781.JPG)
But if I type `install vga=771 noapic nolapic` as in the example the shell says me `Could not find kernel image: install`

Comment: did you just add `noapic` and `nolapic` becuase from your menu clearly there is no kernel image being specified.

Comment: So what can I type in there?

Comment: it should be straight forward, press `F6` and there will be `acpi=off` options.

Comment: @AizuddinZali F6? when? In that screen? I only can type commands what am I missing?

Comment: If you refer back to the link that I posted earlier, when u boot it using CD, you will have from `F1` to `F6` option. `acpi=off` can be sets from `F6` option.

Comment: When I boot with the USB drive I don't have the F1-F6 option, I can only go to Help, in the help screen I can use F6 and I go to the screen I posted in the last message. From there I don't know how I can disable acpi :(

Comment: @AizuddinZali I finally succeed! I had to tap `tab` in the installation menu so I could be able to type `acpi=off nomodeset` and the installation started. Now I'm installing Ubuntu but I want to ask if I have to do something in order to be able to use the pc normally. I have to disable acpi forever? and what about nomodeset?

Comment: Look like your ACPI somehow not supported yet. By right, this error can be ignored. you dont need `nomodeset` if you have no problem with graphic eg. flickering during bootloader to OS.